# array of pointers of a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm having a really bad time with pointers and arrays and i really need help.

There is an exercise that have this struct:

```
typedef struct student_node{
  unsigned number;
  const char *name;
  unsigned class;
  struct student_node *next;
} StudentNode;
```

And i have to implement this function:

```
void groupStudentByClass(StudentNode *classes[], StudentNode students[], size_t num_students)
```

My problem is i want to change something like the number in classes and print the value and i can't. It gives me "Segmentation fault(core dumped)". But i don't understand why...

This is the test code:

```
size_t nClasses=3;
StudentNode *classes [nClasses];
classes[0]->number=0;
printf("%u\n",classes[0]->number);
```

Btw i can't use malloc and things that allocate memory.

Comment: on stackoverflow.com, when asking a question about a run time problem (as this question is doing) there are certain requirements. Post the actual input, Post the actual output, Post the expected output, Post a short, complete, cleanly compiles code that still exhibits the problem.  In this instance, the requirements for the posted code are not being met.  That requirement about the code not being met makes this question off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matthias has already explained why you are getting the segv.

If you cannot use malloc then you need to preallocate the structures.  Something like

```
const size_t MAX_STUDENT = 1024;
StudentNode studentPool[MAX_STUDENT];
int studentLast = -1;
```

Then you need an allocation routine

```
StudentNode* StudentGet()
{
    if (++studentLast >= MAX_STUDENT)
    {
        /* Print error message and exit */
    }
    return studentPool[studentLast];
}
```

Next, when you need to allocate

```
classes[0] = StudentGet();
```

Then you can do your assignments and prints.

You may also need to write routines to free the structures and return them to the pool.

Comment: Thank you. With your answer i think i know what i have to do. I have a array of pointers that point to nClasses structs. And since they are all pointers and they are in the read only part. So i have to use the next pointer to point to the students. This part is still not well burnt in my brain but i think I'm getting it. Once again thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
StudentNode *classes [nClasses];
```

Only creates 3 pointers. But they point to nothing. 
Thus

```
classes[0]
```

does not exist in the memory.

I think, you should use the pointers you get by the arguments of your function.

Comment: Thank you. With your answer i think i know what i have to do. I have a array of pointers that point to nClasses structs. And since they are all pointers and they are in the read only part. So i have to use the next pointer to point to the students. This part is still not well burnt in my brain but i think I'm getting it. Once again thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
StudentNode *classes [nClasses];
```

Allocates an array of 3 pointers, but these pointers are `NULL` at best (worse, they can contain any arbitrary garbage). Even though you can't use malloc (I assume it's a part of the homework), you can put your `student_node` structs on the stack, like this:

```
StudentNode s0 = {
  .number = 0,
  .name = "Alice",
  .class = 0,
};

StudentNode s1 = {
  .number = 1,
  .name = "Bob",
  .class = 0,
};

StudentNode s2 = {
  .number = 2,
  .name = "Peter",
  .class = 0,
};
```

And then chain them together:

```
s0.next = &s1;
s1.next = &s2;
// leave s2.next NULL
```

And then, finally, you can assign the first student in your chain to `classes[0]`:

```
classes[0] = &s0;
```

Comment: Thank you. With your answer i think i know what i have to do. I have a array of pointers that point to nClasses structs. And since they are all pointers and they are in the read only part. So i have to use the next pointer to point to the students. This part is still not well burnt in my brain but i think I'm getting it. Once again thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need a pointer to a pointer in classes. What you really want to do in your test code would be

```
size_t nClasses=3;
StudentNode classes [nClasses];
classes[0].number=0;
printf("%u\n",classes[0].number);
```

Also since you cant use malloc I recommend doing this for the defination

```
typedef struct student_node{
  unsigned number;
  const char name[100];  // or whatever max name size you want
  unsigned class;
  struct student_node *next;
} StudentNode;
```

Comment: Thank you. With your answer i think i know what i have to do. I have a array of pointers that point to nClasses structs. And since they are all pointers and they are in the read only part. So i have to use the next pointer to point to the students. This part is still not well burnt in my brain but i think I'm getting it. Once again thank you :)